# Is it conventional for Java Bean Classes to have more functionality than just getters/setters?

Tags: java, mysql, javabeans

Quick background:

I am looking at refactoring one of my previous class projects as a fun exercise. The project was creating a Course Registration system and using .txt files as the database. As an exercise for myself, I've been learning how to work with SQL databases. From watching lynda.com videos, I downloaded and installed MAMP where I am using Apache Server and mySQL database.

With that said, one of the requirements of the project was for the list of Courses to be displayed in alphabetical order. I had a Course.java class that implemented Comparable. I implemented compareTo(Course course) and that allowed me to call Collections.sort(coursesArrayList) on an ArrayList.

On initialization, my code did the following steps:

1. Read in lines from a Course.txt database.
2. Create Course objects and insert into an ArrayList
3. Call Collections.sort() on the arraylist.

Question:

As I was learning about Java Beans in the lynda.com videos and doing a little research online, it made me question whether it is "conventional" to implement Comparable and compareTo() in a Java Bean Class. If it is NOT conventional, how do you recommend going about sorting an ArrayList which consists of Java Beans?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you are using a database you just `SELECT ... ORDER BY Column` so all your ordering issues are solved else where

Comment: Wow! That was easy enough! But in general, is it conventional for a Java Bean Class to have more than just getters/setters?

Comment: You need compareTo() because you read your data from a text file that perhaps is not sorted, and you need to show this data sorted.  But if you use a database (like MySQL or other) then you do a select .. order by, and get the data sorted.  And you can use Hibernate or JPA that is better when you have beans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would not be against the JavaBeans specification to implement Comparable in a JavaBeans class. (The spec requires a default constructor, getters and setters according to naming conventions, and being Serializable.)

However, I would not implement Comparable based on the title order just because your assignment included printing in that order. Most likely, a course will have an id, and sorting based on that might be just as desirable. Or the number of attendants.

But being a JavaBean, your Course can be sorted any old way just by

```
courses.sort( Comparator.comparing( Course::getTitle ) );          // by title
courses.sort( Comparator.comparing( Course::getAttendantCount ) ); // by attendant count
```

(This requires Java 8.)

Comment: Thanks for answering the main question!